# Как я могу сделать так чтоб данные которые берутся из базы выводилось на страницу по определенному порядку?

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

у меня есть таблица в Базе называется Таблица соответствии
это у меня models.py

```
class Theriology_table_of_matches(models.Model):
kingdom= models.CharField(max_length=250)
type= models.CharField(max_length=250)
klass= models.CharField(max_length=250)
order= models.CharField(max_length=250)
suborder= models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
superfamily= models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
family= models.CharField(max_length=250)
subfamily= models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
tribus= models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
genus= models.CharField(max_length=250)
subgenus= models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
species= models.CharField(max_length=250)
subspecies= models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
author= models.CharField(max_length=250)
ru_name= models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
en_name= models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
kz_name= models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
species_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

это html file

```
<ul class="parent">

    {% for ttype, klasses in data.items %}
    <li >
        <details >
            <summary>-Тип: {{ ttype }}</summary>
            <ul>
                {% for klass, orders  in klasses.items %}
                <li>
                    <details>
                        <summary>- Класс: {{ klass }}</summary>
                    
                    <ul>
                        {% for order, families  in orders.items %}

                        <li> 
                            <details>
                                <summary>- Порядок: {{ order }}</summary>


                                <ul>
                                    {% for family, items  in families.items %}
                                    <li>
                                        <details>
                                                    <summary>- Семейство: {{ family }}</summary>
                                        
                                        <ul>
                                        {% for item in items %}
                                                
                                                <p>  <a href="{{item.species_id}}"> <i> {{item.genus}} {{item.species}} </i> /  {{item.kz_name|default_if_none:"&nbsp;"}} / {{item.ru_name|default_if_none:"&nbsp;"}} / {{item.en_name|default_if_none:"&nbsp;"}} </a> </p>
                                                    
                                                    
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        </ul>
                                        </details>
                                    </li>
    
                                    {% endfor %}

                                </ul>


                            </details>
                        </li>
              
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    </details>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </details>
    </li>   
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[image: Результат выходит так]

Ноооо есть список классификации по которой они должны быть по этому списку
[image: Вот список классификации]

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)